# Determine the minimum and maximum values of an integral subject to end conditions

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

> Determine the minimum and maximum values of the integral
>
> $$\int_0^1 yy'dx$$
>
> subject to the conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$.

There is no explicit dependence on $y$, so our Euler-Lagrange Equation is

$$F-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=\text{constant}$$

However, when I do this, I get $y'y-y'y=0$. This tells me that

$$F=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$$

Thus, the max/min correspond to those x-values where

$$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$$

How do I take it from here? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $yy'=\frac12(y^2)'$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, so I saw a mistake in my above derivation (I should have yy'-y'=c), but I don't really see how the above would help me. Where do the boundary conditions come in to play?

Comment: $\int_0^1 yy'dx = \frac12(y^2(1)-y^2(0))$.